# Как объединить медиа-запросы SASS?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Есть 4 медиа-запроса для ширины экранов. Допустим я хочу применить к определенному размеру экрана определенное свойство SASS к определенному селектору. Как сделать так, чтобы в конечном CSS оставалось 4 медиа-запроса, а не "спагетти" из медиа-запросов?

**SASS файл:**

```
@mixin xs-width($num){
    @media screen and ( min-width: 320px) {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
    }
}

@mixin sm-width($num){
    @media screen and ( min-width: 480px) {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
    }
}

@mixin md-width($num){
    @media screen and ( min-width: 768px) {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
    }
}

@mixin lg-width($num){
    @media screen and ( min-width: 1024px) {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
    }
}

.test {
    @include xs-width (12);
    @include sm-width (6);
    @include md-width (4);
    @include lg-width (3);
}

.test-2 {
    @include xs-width (12);
    @include sm-width (6);
    @include md-width (4);
    @include lg-width (3);
}
```

**Конечный CSS:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .test {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .test {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .test {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .test {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .test-2 {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .test-2 {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .test-2 {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .test-2 {
    width: calc(100%*($num/12));
  }
}
```

**А надо вот так (под каждый экран):**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
      .test {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
      }
      .test-2 {
        width: calc(100%*($num/12));
      }
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mqpacker

Comment: @yozhezhi, я через ruby делаю. Спасибо за инфу :)

Comment: Советую использовать **css-mqpacker**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел [решение](https://github.com/aaronjensen/sass-media_query_combiner) от aaronjensen. Библиотека собирает кучу медиа-запросов в один при компиляции.